Button to trigger download function in JavaScript code is not working, while it is working as expected outside the LWC
I created a LWC to read a query data from CRM Analytics and download an Excel/CSV file. I am able to download the query data as .xls file but I want to convert it into csv file. Following is the code I wrote to convert JSON data to CSV (on an hardcoded array for now) but it is throwing error. This code is working as expected when I trigger it without using it in lwc.
Please Help!
JavaScript Code:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class DownloadCsv extends LightningElement {
results = [{'A': "ABC1", 'B':1}, {'A': "ABC2", 'B':2}];
columnHeader = ['Name', 'Number'];

downloadExcelfile() {
console.log('Hey12'); //Testing if the JS code is deployed

//Creating HTML table
let doc = '<table>';
// Add styles for the table
// doc += '<style>';
// doc += 'table, th, td {';
// doc += ' border: 1px solid black;';
// doc += ' border-collapse: collapse;';
// doc += '}';
// doc += '</style>';
// Add all the Table Headers
doc += '<tr>';
this.columnHeader.forEach(element => {
    doc += '<th>'+ element +'</th>'
});
doc += '</tr>';
// Add the data rows
this.results.forEach(record => {
    doc += '<tr>';
    doc += '<th>'+record.B+'</th>';
    doc += '<th>'+record.A+'</th>';
    doc += '</tr>';
});
doc += '</table>';
console.log(doc);

let csvContent = this.convertTableToCSV(doc);
this.downloadCSV(csvContent, "table.csv");
}

downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
    
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;

    // CSV file
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], { type: "text/csv" });
    console.log(csvFile);
    // Download link
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    console.log(downloadLink);
    // File name
    downloadLink.download = filename;
                
    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

    // Hide download link
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    // Add the link to DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Click download link
    downloadLink.click();
}
convertTableToCSV(doc) {
    var csv = [];
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let docNode = parser.parseFromString(doc, 'text/html');
    let table = docNode.querySelector('table');

    //Loop through table rows
    let rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
    rows.forEach(row => {
        let rowData = [];
        let cells = row.querySelectorAll('th, td'); // Fix: Change rows to row
        cells.forEach(cell => {
            rowData.push(cell.textContent.trim())
        });
        csv.push(rowData.join(','));
    });
    console.log(rows);
    return csv.join('\n');


    
    
    
    
    // let rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    // for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    //     let row = [];
    //     let cells = rows[i].querySelectorAll('th', 'td');
    //     for (let j = 0; j<cells.length; j++) {
    //         let cellText = cells[j].textContent.trim()
    //         row.push(cellText);
    //     }
    //     csv.push(row.join(','));
    // }

    // return csv.join('\n');
    // var rows = doc.split("</tr>");

    // for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    //     var row = [], cells = rows[i].split("</th>");

    //     for (var j = 0; j < cells.length - 1; j++) {
    //         // Extract text content between opening and closing tags and remove HTML tags
    //         var cellText = cells[j].substring(cells[j].indexOf('>') + 1)
    //                                 .replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ""); // Remove HTML tags
    //         row.push(cellText);
    //     }

    //     csv.push(row.join(","));
    // }

    // return csv.join("\n");
}




clickButton() {
    // let data =5;
    this.downloadExcelfile();
}
}

HTML Code:
<template>
<lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="Download as CSV 20240411" title="Download as 
CSV 20240411" onclick={clickButton} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
</template>


What error does it throw, in which line? Do you use Lightning Locker? Does this explain it, in that case?
